# Problems calling web api from JQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, knockout-mapping-plugin

I facing some issues while consuming JSon data from JQuery.

```
  $(function () {
           $.getJSON("/api/Movies", function (data) {
        // ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
    });
```

This piece of code is throwing below exception.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'context': object is null or undefined

I have tested the WebAPI from fiddler it is working fine.

Comment: Is the action you are calling something that you can list the code for?  I actually sounds (to me) that you have an issue with the webapi not the jQuery.  Also where is your "context" object?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not close the parens:

```
 $(function () {
    $.getJSON("/api/Movies", function (data) {
        // ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
    });
 });
```

Also you did not define `viewModel`

Comment: The OP isn't passing anything to the action on his webapi and the error sounds like it would be from the service.

Comment: @jlafay why does he **have to** pass anything?

Comment: Neal, I have the neat compiled code. Here i posted the code snippet. To narrow down the issue, i have commented the code of KO